# how do I create gnome-terminal from python code?

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

I use ubuntu 14.04 and I want to create gnome-terminal from python script. I used the following code.

the code :

```
!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen,PIPE 
import os 
import time

os.system('gnome-terminal') 
time.sleep(5)
print "this works"
```

but when I execute  this code, the system shows following error and the system dosen't read other line ( print "this works" )

```
(gnome-terminal:2179): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
```

**How do I solve this problem?**

thanks for advance

Comment: Your code has many flaws and redundancies..kepping those aside replace `os.system('gnome-terminal')` with `Popen(['gnome-terminal'])` and then check..

Comment: I am not sure what your goal is; do you wantto open the terminal and then have 'this works' typed into the terminal?

Comment: AKmin, did you notice my question? (and is `!/usr/bin/python` a typo?)